# in Python, dictionary sort by value, but only return key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Im using Python 3.3.1 (newbie)

I have a dictionary with a integer key and integer value
I need to sort this dictionary and return a list of key where the value falls below a threshold (say 't')

so far I have

```
list_integer = sorted(dict_int_int.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]  )
```

this sorts the dictionary by value -- everything is fine so far, but how do I limit the values to be below 't' and then ONLY return the keys

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please don't put taglines in your questions.

Comment: Please _do_ put sample input and expected output in your questions.

Comment: abarnert, I don't understand what you mean by not putting sample inputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
[key for key,value in sorted(dic.items() ,key=lambda x : x[1]) if value < threshold]
```

or use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [key for key,value in sorted(dic.items() ,key= itemgetter(1) ) if value < threshold]
```

Comment: this is the correct answer. earlier I made a mistake. but this answer returns ONLY keys. Nice. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
list_integer = filter(lambda x: x[1] < t, dict_int_int.items()))
list_integer = sorted([x[0] for x in list_integer])
```

Comment: I just checked this code and its returning all of the dictionary sorted. the result is no different than what I ran

Comment: He wants the values to be _below_ `t`, but _above_. Also, you're missing the sorting part.

Comment: This can't possibly be returning all of the dictionary. It does return the wrong half of the dictionary, but otherwise, it's correct. Try it with the test data from my answer—it gives you `['a']`, not `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, much less a dictionary.

Comment: @abrnert: Thanks for catching that. I've fixed the code. With your example now it produced ['b', 'c', 'd']

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with what you have:

```
list_integer = sorted(dict_int_int.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

This gives you a list of key-value pairs, sorted by values (which makes the name a bit misleading).

Now let's `limit the values to be below 't'`:

```
list_small = ((k, v) for k, v in list_integer if v < t)
```

(You could also write that as `filter` if you prefer.)

And now, let's `ONLY return the keys`:

```
list_keys = [k for k, v in list_small]
```

Of course you can combine any two of these steps, or even combine all three (in which case you end up with Ashwini Chaudhary's answer).

---

Let's go through these step by step to make sure they work:

```
>>> dict_int_int = {'a': 1.0, 'b': 0.5, 'c': 0.25, 'd': 0.10 }
>>> t = 0.75
>>> list_integer = sorted(dict_int_int.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> list_integer
[('d', 0.1), ('c', 0.25), ('b', 0.5), ('a', 1.0)]
>>> list_small = [(k, v) for k, v in list_integer if v < t]
>>> list_small
[('d', 0.1), ('c', 0.25), ('b', 0.5)]
>>> list_keys = [k for k, v in list_small]
>>> list_keys
['d', 'c', 'b']
```

(Notice that I changed the generator expression `list_small` into a list comprehension. This is because we need to print out its values, and then use them again. A generator expression only lets you use its values once.)