# How to create create a list of keys in order of descending values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.7

Using a dictionary (such as {'aa': 3.0, 'bb': 1.2, 'ab': 3.0, 'cd': 6.0}), I want to return a list of the keys in descending order based on their values. If two or more keys have the same value, then the values will be ordered based on the alphabetical order of the keys. Using the previous dictionary as an example, I want my function to return:
['cd', 'aa', 'ab', 'bb'].

I have thought about creating a helper function to make parallel lists of the keys and their corresponding values to accomplish what I want, but I have not been able to implement this. I've written a very basic outline of my code below:

```
def f(d: Dict[str, float]) -> List[str]:

    accumulator_list = []

    # do something

    return accumulator_list
```

Edit: My question is unique because the other question was asking about a function that returns a list of values below a threshold, while my function has nothing to do with a threshold.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in Python, dictionary sort by value, but only return key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365397/in-python-dictionary-sort-by-value-but-only-return-key)

Comment: create list with tuples `(-3.0, 'aa')` (value with minus)  and use `sorted()` to sort it

Comment: @furas do you mean sort() ?

Comment: there is `sorted(data)` and `data.sort()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create list with tuples like `(-3.0, 'aa')` - value as first and with minus so it will sort by value descending and by key ascending.

And then you can sort it using `sorted()`

```
data = {'aa': 3.0, 'bb': 1.2, 'ab': 3.0, 'cd': 6.0}

new = [(-value, key) for key, value in data.items()]
new = sorted(new)
new = [key for value, key in new]

print(new)

['cd', 'aa', 'ab', 'bb']
```

Or you can do the same directly in `sorted` using `key=`

```
data = {'aa': 3.0, 'bb': 1.2, 'ab': 3.0, 'cd': 6.0}

new = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
new = [key for key, value in new]

print(new)
```

in one line

```
data = {'aa': 3.0, 'bb': 1.2, 'ab': 3.0, 'cd': 6.0}

new = [key for key, value in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))]

print(new)
```

Answer (score 1):

First sort the keys in alphabetical order, then sort them in reverse order of their value. Because Python sort is stable, this will keep the keys in alphabetical order when their values are the same:

```
def f(d):
    keys = sorted(d)
    keys = sorted(keys, key=lambda k: d[k], reverse=True)
    return keys

d = {'aa': 3.0, 'bb': 1.2, 'ab': 3.0, 'zz': 6.0, 'cd': 6.0}
print(f(d))
```

output:

```
['cd', 'zz', 'aa', 'ab', 'bb']
```

From the sorting documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts

Answer (score 1):

This is a great use case for [itemgetter()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

d = {'aa': 3.0, 'bb': 1.2, 'ab': 3.0, 'cd': 6.0}

tups = list(d.items())
tups.sort(key = itemgetter(0))                   # Sort by keys.
tups.sort(key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)   # Sort by vals, reversed.
keys = list(map(itemgetter(0), tups))

print(keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [dict's documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Dictionaries have a method called `keys`, which returns an iterator with the keys. You can get a sorted list from the iterator with `sorted`.

In your example:

```
d = {'aa': 3.0, 'bb': 1.2, 'ab': 3.0, 'cd': 6.0}
l = sorted(d.keys()) # l = ['aa','ab','bb','cd']
```

Other useful iterators of dictionaries are `items` and `values`.